# Limit search in OpenLayers with Nominatim to a certain city

Tags: openlayers, javascript, nominatim, ol-ext

I'm using `ol.control.SearchNominatim` for address search.

However, I would like to limit the search to only one country, state and city.

For example: country = Brazil, state = Sao Paulo, city ​​= Sao Paulo

Is it possible?

```
var searchNominatim = new ol.control.SearchNominatim (
{   
    reverse: false,
    polygon: false,
    //url: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html?city=S%C3%A3o+Paulo&county=Brasil&state=Regi%C3%A3o+Imediata+de+S%C3%A3o+Paulo,
    position: true, // Search, with priority to geo position
    placeholder: "Search",
    target: $("#search > div").get(0)
});
```

Comment: You would need to specify the `viewbox` for the city https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Search/#result-limitation https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/doc/doc-pages/ol.control.SearchNominatim.html  Since that is a rectangle it would not guarantee the result would be inside the city boundary, which is unlikely to be rectangular.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didn't work. I tried to write the filters in the url but it didn't work either.  `url: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html?city=S%C3%A3o+Paulo&county=Brasil&state=Regi%C3%A3o+Imediata+de+S%C3%A3o+Paulo`

Comment: You also need to set `bounded` when you use `viewbox`.  If you first find the city with nominatim you can use the geometry to set the viewbox https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-tuzse7?file=/main.js

Comment: Mike, thank you.
Sorry to write as an answer and not as a comment. But it's been a while and I can't log into the account I asked the question anymore..
Thank you and sorry for the delay in getting back to you. I've tested your code, but it's still not working exactly as I need it. For example, I typed Rua Oratório, and it showed in the select box several streets with the same name and some are not in the city of São Paulo. I would like to filter so that they only show the streets of a certain city.

Comment: Nominatin with a `q=` as used by ol-ext query can only filter by a viewbox extent.  You would need to override the ol-ext response handler to filter out results inside that extent which do not intersect the city geometry https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-swyn8w?file=/main.js

Answer (score 0):

use country code and city code:

```
var requestData = searchNominatim.requestData.bind(searchNominatim);
    searchNominatim.requestData = function(e){
        var data = requestData(e);
        data.countrycodes = 'countrycode,citycode,...';
        return data;
};
```

you can find your country/city code on google